# How to store and use Cookies in salesforce lightning

Tags: lightning

I do see a post on the same question but that is not answered.

I need to expose my lightning components via sites(literally a public site ) . i'm using lightning components in VF page via lightning out. then I use VF page in Sites.
 Component one (VF Page 1 is holding this comp 1) - has login details (user name, password) .  After login success, I want to use the logged in user name in multiple components(VF Page 2 holding this comp 2). In other words, i need to carry the logged in user details through out the site. How to achieve this? Any help would be appreciated.

We don't have enough salesforce licence for all our users.

Comment: I think you can use apex to create cookies instead of javascript. When users login you can create cookies from apex method...and further when page loaded..you can check in apex method for same cookie.. 
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_sites_cookie.htm

Comment: I suggest you also review your design with your Salesforce account executive to be sure it complies with Salesforce's licensing terms.